# Convert Primefaces theme to look like material design UI

Tags: user-interface, jsf, primefaces, material-design

I need to convert my primefaces theme to look like material design theme.All the input box,dropdowns and calender etc should be look like the material design.
I tried with below URL but got stuck in select box and calendar design:

http://materializecss.com/

Please suggest some approach or getting the UI look like material design in primefaces.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your best is to go with something like this:

https://www.primefaces.org/layouts/ultima/

Primefaces uses many styling code to make ready-to-go components. This has a benefit, you only need to use them. But when it comes to change their style you'll find many issues regarding to layouts, background images, and so on. So if this is a client requirement I wouldn't hesitate to buy a theme, otherwise you'll need many hours to make the changes yourself and the result might be quite disappointing.

Another choice might be just to use [material styling](https://getmdl.io/started/index.html) and raw JSF. It depends on what kind of components you need. Also, starting from April 2018 you've got a brand new [PF designer API](https://www.primefaces.org/introducing-primefaces-designer-api/), in which you can design your own theme. You need a license to use it, though.

Comment: Or use https://www.primefaces.org/introducing-primefaces-designer-api/ cheaper than a full theme but you should do all the work yourself but way more easy than to customize the components by overriding the css

Comment: @Kukeltje I see you're totally up to date with PF stuff! Altering the PF components has been a nightmare (I've spent many hours fixing styles). However, it seems that the team has provided new cool tools (even if you need to buy a license to use them). Answer updated ;-)